# (How) is it possible in SwiftUI to edit (length unit) measurements in a TextField?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to save a houses height in a `Measurement<UnitLength>` type variable.
I would now like to edit this value easily via a `TextField` in SwiftUI. Is there any cool way to do that?

I found out that SwiftUI `TextField` provides a constructor that takes a `value` (just a binding to a variable) and `format` (which must be a `ParsableFormatStyle`). I did my research about this new protocol (the format style) but did not find a lot. It seems there is a `ParsableFormatStyle.measurement()` value that seems to be perfect for that, but if I use it as my format for the TextField, my compiler complains about the whole class (type checking) without providing any useful information. I also tried to use a `Measurement<UnitLength>.FormatStyle` as my format, but then my compiler complains that `Initializer 'init(_:value:format:prompt:)' requires that 'Measurement<UnitLength>.FormatStyle' conform to 'ParseableFormatStyle'`.

This is my approach I described lastly:

```
private let heightFormatStyle = Measurement<UnitLength>.FormatStyle(width: .abbreviated, usage: MeasurementFormatUnitUsage<UnitLength>.general)

(...)

TextField("Height", value: $measurementValueOfUnitLength, format: heightFormatStyle) // <<-- error as described above
```

Thank you very very much in advance for your help! I would like to find the best and convenient solution for editing my height value via a TextField.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not devise a cool way to use the `Measurement` formatting.
However, there is a good article on how you can build your own `ParseableFormatStyle`, here: https://emptytheory.com/2021/08/14/creating-custom-parseable-format-styles-in-ios-15/

A simplistic working alternative approach is this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var txt = ""
    @State private var houseHeight = Measurement(value: 0.0, unit: UnitLength.meters)

    var formatter: MeasurementFormatter {
        let fmt = MeasurementFormatter()
        fmt.unitOptions = .providedUnit
        fmt.unitStyle = .long
        return fmt
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 55) {
            Text("Height: " + formatter.string(from: houseHeight))
            TextField("Height", text: $txt).border(.red)
                .onChange(of: txt) { val in
                    if let metre = Double(val) {
                        houseHeight = Measurement(value: metre, unit: UnitLength.meters)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your alternative input!

Comment: did my "simplistic" answer provided you with a working solution?

Comment: Thanks again, yeah, I build it like that for now. An option would be to display the current measurement unit next to the TextField and make it selectable. The TextField is only used to display and change the plain value, as in your answer. Seems to be the best solution since there is no TextField handling measurements provided by Apple/SwiftUI